# Trouble searching with django-haystack facing error - undefined field django_ct

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I am totally new to django haystack and i am facing troubles getting started with it.

when i search i get error

```
Failed to query Solr using '*:*': [Reason: Error 400 undefined field django_ct]
```

when i rebuild index i get this error

```
WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index in connection 'default'. Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y
Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
All documents removed.
ERROR:root:Error updating votingapp using default
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
...
index_qs = self.index_queryset(using=using)
TypeError: index_queryset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'using'
```

I have set up a simple index class

```
class QuestionsIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    qs = indexes.CharField(model_attr='question')

    def get_model(self):
        return Questions

    def index_queryset(self):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

added code in settings.py

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr'
        # ...or for multicore...
        # 'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/mysite',
    },
}
```

added the url

```
url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
```

view code

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print SearchQuerySet().all()
    return render_to_response('search.html',{})
```

Kindly advise where am i doing wrong

Comment: You havent added the `using=None` keyworded parameter of `index_queryset()`. It should be `index_queryset(self, using=None)` if you want that keyword that is.

Comment: hey thanks , now i get this error while rebuilding -->Failed to add documents to Solr: [Reason: Error 400 ERROR: [doc=votingapp.questions.1] unknown field 'django_ct']. Can you tell me good reference to understand haystack working

Comment: Does your `schema.xml` have a `django_ct` field? Good docs are the actual docs -> https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.7/tutorial.html

Comment: i havent build schema.xml in solr, i thought haystack would build it with the search_indexes.py

Comment: No, you have to run the management command `manage.py build_solr_schema` if you havent done that.

Comment: yeah i had done that already

Comment: Allright, well, `django_ct` is field that has to be added manually. add it and it should work! :) Also make sure that you're querying the correct server and not the example server in your settings.

Comment: hi limelight thanks for your help. I am running this code locally in development environment, how do u say i am using example server .. are u pointing to solr server?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the question!
After facing up with the same error, I finally found the problem. For me it was the solr version that haystack did not manage to handle. 
I installed https://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/3.5.0/apache-solr-3.5.0.tgz
following step by step: 
http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing_search_engines.html#solr
With the same conf than you.
Hope this will work for you.
Cheers, 
Max